# Read Multiple Big Files in Using C# Async Programming

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, streamreader

I want to read multiple files that may contains millions of rows.

1. Files are multiple i want to multiple files simultaneously.
2. Each file contains millions of rows so if read lines sequentially it will take time. So i want to read multiple line simultaneously.
3. On each line read do some processing based on value in line.

I have few queries.

Question:
As file read is I/O operations so to read multiple files at the same time will using Async programming should i use

1. Simple async/await model
2. Task.Run(Read_File(filePath))

Comment: Since there is Async File I/O API in dotnet, you should use it: [Asynchronous File I/O](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/asynchronous-file-i-o) , [Using Async for File Access (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/using-async-for-file-access)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you read a file, especially a file on a hard disk, the reading is relatively slow, because the device has to wait until the correct sector is under the read head. Reading multiple files at the same time, won't improve performance, because after reading a sector of file A, the read head has to move to read a sector of file B and move back to read the next sector of file A.

So it's not wise to read two files simultaneously.

What you want to do, screams for the producer-consumer pattern: a producer produces data as fast as it can, while a consumer processes the data in a different speed: sometimes slower than the producer, sometimes faster. Data that is not processed yet has to be buffered.

If you use a producer-consumer pattern, the producer reads the files and puts the read lines on the buffer as fast as possible. Whenever the file reader has to await for the next  batch of data, the consumer has some time to process the already produced lines.

Microsoft provided a simple Nuget package for this: [Microsoft Task Parallel Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl)

First you create a Buffer. All read lines will be stored on this buffer:

```
private BufferBlock<string> buffer = new BufferBlock<string>();
```

The async procedure to read the files and store the read lines on the buffer:

```
async Task ProduceLinesAsync(string fileName)
{
    using (TextReader fileReader = File.OpenText(fileName))
    {
        string readLine = await fileReader.ReadLineAsync();
        while (readLine != null)
        {
            // a line has been read; put it on the buffer:
            buffer.SendAsync(readLine);

            // read the next line                
            readLine = await fileReader.ReadLineAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

The procedure to process a number of files:

```
async Task ProduceLinesAsync(IEnumerable<string> fileNames)
{
    foreach (var fileName in fileNames)
    {
        await ProduceLinesAsync(fileName);
    }

    // If here, nothing to produce anymore.
    // tell the buffer that producing is finished:
    buffer.Complete();
}
```

If needed, you can let each file Produce data on a different buffer, and have one consumer per buffer.

**Consumer**

You see all the awaits while producing: whenever the process is awaiting for the next line to be read, the consumer will have time to process already produced lines:

```
Task ConsumeAsync()
{
    while (await buffer.OutputAvailableAsync())
    {
        // there is something on the buffer; fetch it and process it:
        var line = await buffer.ReceiveAsync();
        this.ProcessLine(line);
    }

    // if here, producer marked Complete(), indicating that no data is to be expected
}
```

Put it all together:

```
async Task ProcessFiles(IEnumerable<string> fileNames)
{
    // start producing, but do not await:
    Task taskProduce = ProduceLinesAsync(fileNames);

    // because we did not await, we are free to do the following as soon as the
    // TextReader has to await for a line.
    // again, do not await.
    Task taskConsume = ConsumeAsync();

    // await until both the producer and the consumer are finished:
    await Task.WhenAll(new Task[] {taskProduce, taskConsume})
}
```

### Conclusion

By using the BufferBlock in async await, The process will only be waiting idly when all data has been processed, and the next line has not been read.

In all other cases, whenever your process has to await for the TextReader to produce the next line, it will be processing lines that are not processed yet. Your process will never wait idly while there is work to do.

Answer (score 4):

You won't save time by reading multiple files simultaneously, unless each file is located in a different storage hardware. The speed by which you can read files from the filesystem is limited by the capabilities of the storage hardware where the files are located, not the capabilities of the CPU.

What you could do to save time is to read the files in an uninterrupted workflow, and process the lines in a different workflow, with the two workflows working concurrently and  independently. The communication between the two workflows, the producer workflow and the consumer workflow, can be achieved using an intermediate buffer, with either blocking or async capabilities. There are many options available, including the [`BlockingCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1) class, the [`Channels`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/), and the [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) library.